# Difference between Prometheus and Chronosphere?

Tags: prometheus, monitoring

Difference between Prometheus  and Chronosphere monitoring tool? can we use it together??

Answer (score 1):

(Full disclosure: I work at Chronosphere)

They interoperate. Prometheus is an open source monitoring tool and Chronosphere is SaaS-based cloud native observability. Prometheus is *also* one of several open source tools (along with OpenTelemetry, Jaeger, Fluentd, etc.) that can be used as a collector for Chronosphere. You can also use PromQL to query and retrieve results from Chronosphere. The Chronosphere blog has a bunch of posts about using Prometheus (including [some PromQL query-writing tips](https://chronosphere.io/learn/an-introduction-to-the-four-primary-types-of-prometheus-metrics/)).

[Here's an article](https://dzone.com/articles/o11y-guide-keeping-your-cloud-native-observability) about different kinds of open source collectors and tools (like Prometheus) that you could adopt to keep your options open to future-proof your observability/monitoring/tracing stack.